# Pass JSON data from php file to javascript file using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, leaflet

Trying to grab a json variable from a php file and pass to a javascript file.
I'm making a leaflet map and I store the information for markers in a mysql database, I then use a php file to pull that information and put it into an array.

**The problem:** For some reason the Javascript file is not using the data correctly and I can't figure out why.

get-data.php

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'testuser', 'testpassword', 'testdb');
if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}


$queryStmt = 'SELECT * FROM test';

$geojson = array(
            'type' =>   'FeatureCollection',
            'features' => array()
);

if($result = $db->query($queryStmt)) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        extract($row);
        $markers = array(
            'type' => 'Feature',
            'properties'        => array (
                'name'          => $name,
                'type'          => $type,
                'id'            => $id,
                'country'       => $country,
                'territory'     => $territory,
                ),
                'geometry'      => array(
                'type'          => 'Point',
                'coordinates'   => array($long,$lat)
                )
            );  

        array_push($geojson['features'], $markers);
}
};

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($geojson, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$db = NULL;
```

data.js

```
var result = [];
$.get("get-data.php", function(geojson) {
    result = geojson;
}); 

capitolsLayer = L.geoJson(result, {
//lots of stuff with maps and everything
```

index.php (where all the map code actually goes)

```
<script type="text/javascript" source="data.js"></script>
<script>
//lots of map code
var map = L.map();
capitolsLayer.addTo(map);
</script>
```

In the ajax call of data.js I tried adding

```
alert(result);
```

And what popped up was just [object Object]

On index.php no errors are shown the markers just simply don't appear.

**EDIT**
**Update with solution!**
After a lot of reading and learning and LOTS of digging I found the answer!
I changed this:

```
$.get("get-data.php", function(data) {
    result = data;
}); 
capitols = new L.geoJson(result, {
//map stuff here
```

To this:

```
$.getJSON("get-data.php", function(data) {
    capitols.addData(data);
}).complete;

capitols = new L.geoJson(null, {
//map stuff here
```

Comment: `[object Object]` is actually a good sign that you already have what you wanted... (js objects don't self-serialize like they would in a var_dump)

Comment: yeah I figured but I can't understand why the markers are not appearing on the map if the data was successfully brought over, looking at the php file and see what it outputs and it's in the correct format and everything.

Comment: cool, now all you need to do is move your marker populating code to the callback where `result` lives (you can't "export" it out of the callback, so you need to bring the code to the data)

Comment: I did not know that, sorry if this is a stupid question but couldn't I just add "return result" and "export" the json data out of the callback? I tired it and it doesn't work but I guess i'm just confused as to why you can't "export" the data.

Comment: well, you can push the data out of the callback, but the callback does one other thing that you need: it waits until the data is available until running the code. if you push it out, you still need to find a way to make the other data-needing parts wait. While you could do some kind of polling, that's ugly, slow, and rush risky. basically, you need to just bite the bullet of async JS and refactor away from a top-down flow. there's no easy workaround, save some generator abuse in ES6...

Comment: thank you for the help :) pointed me in the right direction to find the answer! updated my question with the solution I found

Comment: Coming back to this after several months and just wanted to thank you again dandavis, I've done more projects on the site I made this map for and the tips/info you gave me here really helped.  I realize now that I was -completely- misunderstanding how ajax worked.  If anyone is reading this post looking for their own answers, take a good look and read up on how async actually works, will probably help a lot.

Comment: most things that are actually worth doing are not easy. glad to help. async can take an adjustment or two mentally, but after a little while it "clicks" and you then wonder what all the fuss what about...

Answer (score 1):

Try this way parsing the JSON data and accessing at json object..

```
var result = [];
$.get("get-data.php", function(geojson) {
    result = JSON.parse(geoJson);
    alert (result.properties.name);
});
```